# how to invoke easy templates in org-mode of Emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have tried to type a 'c' in org-mode(actually in a org file) of Emacs, expecting the easy templates as instructed in org-mode manual. But there is nothing coming out. Would anyone please tell me the correct way to invoke easy templates in org-mode. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having problems getting this to work. What I discovered is that you have to be at the beginning of a blank line and then you can type `<cTAB` (using the TAB key, not typing the word) and it works as documented.

I suspect that people who use easy templates have forgotten the caveat that you must be at the beginning of a line and just do it because they have gotten into the habit of doing it that way

Answer (score 0):

From http://orgmode.org/manual/Easy-Templates.html:

"To insert a structural element, type a ‘<’, followed by a template selector and ."

That means you don't type `c`, you type `>c` then press `TAB`. This works for me in Org 8.2. You may well have an older version of org (v7), and I don't know whether this works in org 7.

Comment: If this answer is correct, I will vote to delete the question because it's basically an issue caused by a typo.

Comment: Sorry, the type error only exists in my question posted, actually what I type in emacs does be '<', which makes nothing happened.

Comment: @yangdawei Please add: OS, emacs version, org-mode version, and whether you're using the GUI or emacs in a terminal

Comment: @yangdawei Also, fix your question if you are actually typing `>c`

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04, GNU Emacs 24.3.1 and I don't know how to get version of org-mode. I use Emacs in GUI.

Comment: `M-x org-version` will tell you the org-version

Comment: just do as you said, the version is 7.9.3f

Comment: The easy templates function is OK. Maybe the reason is my wrong operation. @MrBones